# Why /numpy/core/fromnumeric.py raise "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in reduce" when SimpleImputer is applied?

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, runtime, warnings

Sometimes running data science scripts applies transformations to the data. However, some transformations are executed with a warning. The transformed data is obtained but with some warning raised by the library.

As far as possible I want to run code without warnings raised midway.

When SimpleImputer method from [SciKitLearn library](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html)
is applied to this data(github repo below): columns 0 and 1 was imputed normally but from 2 to 6 raise the following warning:

```py
/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:87: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in reduce
  return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
```

How can I to impute data without warnings?

I tried one possible solution:

- Write the dataframe in .csv format and download again. (Impute without warning)

but

- If the dataframe is writen in .pkl format and download again raise warning in some columns not all.

The data and the code to reproduce it is in:

https://github.com/juandevprojects/bugs/tree/main/simple_imputer_warnings

Comment: Warnings don't give much context.  But the `warnings` module can be used change behavior.  They can be silenced.  Or changed to raise an error, and thus give traceback and hopefully identify the problem.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html